# Remove words from string that have a prefix of # or @?

Tags: python

I have a block of text like this:

```
Hello @Simon, I had a great day today. #StackOverflow
```

I want to find the most elegant solution to stripping it down to look like this:

```
Hello, I had a great day today.
```

i.e. I want to strip out all words that have a prefix of # and @.  (And yes, im inspecting tweets)

I am new to python, and I would be ok doing this on single words, but not sure on the best way to achieve this on a string that contains multiple words.

My first thoughts would be to use replace, but that would just strip out the actual @ and # symbols.  **Looking for the best way to strip out any word that has a prefix of # or @.**

-EDIT-
Not sure if it this invalidates the answers give, but for acceptance, I also need to strip out where multiple words contain a prefix of # or $.  e.g. hello #hiya #ello

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hello @Simon, I had a great day today. #StackOverflow'
>>> re.sub(r'(?:^|\s)[@#].*?(?=[,;:.!?]|\s|$)', r'', s)
'Hello, I had a great day today.'
```

Comment: Does this fail if the `@` or `#` occurs in the middle of the word?

Comment: @MarkRansom Improved so that it doesn't.

Comment: Although this works for my example above, this does not seem to catch everything.  e.g. If two hash tags follow each other with a space. See http://pastebin.com/hMWJ1D9W

Comment: @Simon That's because I used a replacement instead of a lookahead. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as writing an anonymous function and putting it in a filter statement

```
' '.join(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in ['@','#'], tweet.split()))
```

This will lose the comma on @users or #topics but if you're just processing the tweets you probably won't miss it.

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of turning multiple spaces into one. Depending on the application this might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
' '.join([w for w in s.split() if len(w)>1 and w[0] not in ['@','#']])
```

Where `s` is your tweet.

Comment: Is `split()` capable of returning a zero-length string?

Comment: Oops. I added some unneeded check indeed. My bad.